# TortoiseGit no Sync option in context menu

Tags: tortoisegit

Disappeared for an unknown reason. Tried restart PC, reinstall, show/hide in git settings, but no luck. Need help, because it was very handy to use this option.

UPD:
TortoiseGit 2.7.0.0
git version 2.11.0.windows.3

Comment: What are your show/hide settings? Does it appear when you hold the shift key?

Comment: I found the anser with "shift key", tried, but it wasn't helpful for me. I saw Git Clone and other options hidden, but Sync...

Answer (score 4):

For those who have the same issue. I found the solution!

1. Right click on git repository folder -> **TortoiseGit** -> **Settings**
2. Find the "**Context Menu**" option and disable **"Sync..."**
3. Find the "**Context Menu 2**" option and enable **"Sync..."**
4. Make sure this option appeared at somewhere here [image: TortoiseGit context menu]
5. Reverse your changes by clicking: "**Context Menu 2**" -> disable **"Sync..."**
6. "**Context Menu**" -> enable "**Sync...**

After that you will see our lost menu item.
If no luck: try disable both options -> save settings (press OK) -> look at TortoiseGit context menu -> try step 6.

P.S. If you are developer of TortoiseGit or a person who know him, please, ask him to fix this bug. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The context menu entries is fully configurable in the settings. Check out if the missing option is configured correct, see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-look-feel

Comment: My options was configured correctly: Context menu -> Sync... was checked and Context menu 2 -> Sync... was not. But changing this options, apparently in a random way, made it appear again.

Comment: TortoiseGit is an open source project with an open issue tracker. If you want to let the developers know your problem, add a new issue at https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you have an outstanding merge. If so, TortoiseGit will not show the Sync option.

Commit the merge, and the option may reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Mag Roader's answer, if you have an issue with merge, you have to abort the merge.
[image]